# jQuery nested Sortable list and php mysql update?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

im working in simple script which have jquery nested sortable lists

i used this plugin to manage the nested lists [this one](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

it just work great but my problem with the backend PHP code which i need to write to update the mysql table im really confused so much about it
this is the final array i got from the ajax request when updating the nested list

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 29
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 32
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
        )

)
```

those are all the ID's pushed from the database

but i have no clue how to update them into the database so they been sorted the right way?

Comment: What is your database schema, and especially how are modelized parent/child relationship and display order ? Would you like an update on each movement, or, at the end when user clicks on 'save' button or similar behaviour ?

Comment: the jquery script i wrote is to update it simultaneously and it work just great problem is not how to manage the parents and child its all about sorting and i created an int filed for this it will have number for sort

Comment: You would have an `order` field for sibbilings, and `parent_id` field for hierarchy. Then parse recursively all elements of the tree to update/create the rows. Maybe another request based on a trimestamp to deletre obsolete rows. How are you doing it ? Note that it is not optimized to re-update all database rows if a user does not change, or only a few fields.